# PHP show random images from directory

Tags: php, image, random, unique

I am kinda new to PHP.

I am searching a way to make PHP showing 6 random JPG images from a directory, no matter what the imagename is. The other important thing is that all the displayed images should be different.

Do you have any idea what's the easiest way to do it?
I know i should use the glob function, but how to limit the images to 6,random and non repeatable?

I have that as code for the moment:

```
<?php
    $pictures = glob("images/gallery/*.jpg"); 
    $no_pictures = count($pictures)-1;  
    $limit = $no_pictures-5;            
    for( $i = $no_pictures; $i >= $limit; $i--){ 
    echo '<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 wow fadeInUp">
            <a class="thumb" href="'.$pictures[$i].'"><img src="'.$pictures[$i].'" alt="Gallery"/><span class="thumb_overlay"></span></a>
          </div>'; 
}  
?>
```

But on image refresh it's not displaying different images, it's just tooking random 6 and keep displaying them all the time.

Comment: a start would be http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

Answer (score -1):

Files: (Random names used)

```
images/header/rotate.php
images/header/abstract.jpg
images/header/bird.jpg
images/header/butterfly.jpg
images/header/happy.jpg
```

HTML:

```
<img src="images/header/rotate.php" alt="Header" width="400" height="100" />
```

PHP:

```
<?php

/*
Check it out for more interesting scripts & downloads

AUTOMATIC IMAGE ROTATOR
Version 2.2 - December 4, 2003
Copyright (c) 2002-2003 Dan P. Benjamin, Automatic, Ltd.
All Rights Reserved.
http://www.hiveware.com/imagerotator.php

*/

$folder = '.';


$extList = array();
$extList['gif'] = 'image/gif';
$extList['jpg'] = 'image/jpeg';
$extList['jpeg'] = 'image/jpeg';
$extList['png'] = 'image/png';


// You don't need to edit anything after this point.


// --------------------- END CONFIGURATION -----------------------

$img = null;

if (substr($folder,-1) != '/') {
$folder = $folder.'/';
}

if (isset($_GET['img'])) {
$imageInfo = pathinfo($_GET['img']);
if (
    isset( $extList[ strtolower( $imageInfo['extension'] ) ] ) &&
      file_exists( $folder.$imageInfo['basename'] )
      ) {
      $img = $folder.$imageInfo['basename'];
    }
    } else {
    $fileList = array();
    $handle = opendir($folder);
    while ( false !== ( $file = readdir($handle) ) ) {
    $file_info = pathinfo($file);
    if (
        isset( $extList[ strtolower( $file_info['extension'] ) ] )
    ) {
        $fileList[] = $file;
    }
}
closedir($handle);

if (count($fileList) > 0) {
    $imageNumber = time() % count($fileList);
    $img = $folder.$fileList[$imageNumber];
    }
}

if ($img!=null) {
    $imageInfo = pathinfo($img);
    $contentType = 'Content-type: '.$extList[ $imageInfo['extension'] ];
        header ($contentType);
     readfile($img);
} else {
if ( function_exists('imagecreate') ) {
    header ("Content-type: image/png");
    $im = @imagecreate (100, 100)
        or die ("Cannot initialize new GD image stream");
    $background_color = imagecolorallocate ($im, 255, 255, 255);
    $text_color = imagecolorallocate ($im, 0,0,0);
    imagestring ($im, 2, 5, 5,  "IMAGE ERROR", $text_color);
    imagepng ($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
    }
}

?>
```

Credits for rotator script
http://old.marcofolio.net/webdesign/php_random_image_rotation.html

Comment: @rtfm Probably is more optimized code to do the same thing, but I've used it and it does work, does not kill the server resources that bad, aside the obvious loading of the images, which is going to happen whichever way you do it.